# “Straight ahead” vs. “straight as you go”

Tags: differences, idioms

Is *straight as you go* used often? What is the main difference to *straight ahead*?

I have heard *straight ahead* in conversations quite a bit, but *straight as you go* doesn’t ring a bell. Perhaps it occurs only in selective states in U.S.A.?

Comment: "Straight as you go" (as part of a set of directions to get somewhere) is "informal/dialectal", but it's perfectly common in the UK as well as US. I doubt anyone would fail to understand it, even if they weren't in the habit of saying it themselves.

Comment: You might want to note that ["then straight as you go"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22then+straight+as+you+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) produces *no results at all* in Google Books, whereas ["then straight ahead"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22then+straight+ahead%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) claims "about 10,300 results" (so don't be tempted to use it just so you'll pass for a native speaker, because it might well backfire! :)

Comment: "Straight as you go" sounds to me like a portmanteau of "Straight ahead" and "Steady as she goes".

Comment: @J.R.: I'd have thought more likely *"[keep going] straight as you go [along]"*, but I don't know.

Comment: I would understand you, find your construction fresh and clever, and assume that you were a seafaring Irishman.

Comment: @FumbleFingers At present, "then straight as you go" produces exactly one hit in the regular Google search, which is (unsurprisingly) this page. Compare to 2.5 million hits for "straight as you go". It's apparently used, but never, ever, ever as a subsequent stage in a set of directions to go somewhere.

Comment: @Marin I suppose that means there definitely is a significant difference in how it's used from how "straight ahead" is used, though I hadn't noticed the phrase before myself.

Comment: @Theodore Murdock: Looks like you're right. I don't have a problem with ["stay straight as you go"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stay+straight+as+you+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but apparently it's not used at all often.

Comment: @Theodore Thanks. Still not sure why the question was closed